# How to use methods from Assert Class

Tags: unit-test, test-setup

According to this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Assert.htm#apex_class_System_Assert) from the Apex reference guide, I can use methods from the Assert class in my test methods but when I am trying this in my code I am getting an error message:-  "Variable does not exist: Assert". Any idea what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Make sure your test class has the correct API version. You need 56.0.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Assert` class was [introduced in Winter '23, API v56.0](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_nc.htm&type=5&release=240).

Classes that use that feature need to be using API v56.0 (which you can set in the accompanying `.cls-meta.xml` file), and the org you're deploying this to also needs to be on the Winter '23 release (which may not happen for your production org until October 14th).

<strike>I'm not sure if you also need to be using v56 for sfdx or not.</strike> <- This doesn't appear to matter.

For now, the safe approach here would be to continue using the old-style assertion methods (`System.assert()`, `System.assertEquals()`, `System.assertNotEquals()`).

Comment: The project API version is not relevant to Apex class files; it is simply the version for metadata that is not explicitly linked to an API version, such as flows.

Comment: @PhilW Doesn't it also determine which version of the REST/Tooling/Metadata APIs gets used? My uncertainty is around whether you can deploy v56 metadata with, say, the v50 API.

Comment: We have deployed newer version apex than the API version for the project (so we don't need to update flows etc. to be able to use newer Apex features).